# decodeFile returns null Bitmap for an existing file

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I have tried all the solutions I could find on stackoverflow to resolve this issue, but in vain. In running the following code, mAlbumPhotoUri is "/mnt/sdcard/photo/1342147146535.jpg" which is Uri type. file.exists() indicates this file exists, but resultBitmap is null, after executing the last line of code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
File file = new File(mAlbumPhotoUri.toString());
if(file.exists()){
   Toast.makeText(this, "File exists in /mnt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
else {
Toast.makeText(this, "File NOT exists in /mnt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; //only get the size of the bitmap                

if (resultPhotoBitmap != null) {
    resultPhotoBitmap.recycle();
    }
String fname=new File(mAlbumPhotoUri.toString()).getAbsolutePath();
resultPhotoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fname, options);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention.. It's Android.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a File Explorer or examining the contents somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the option `inJustDecodeBounds` to your `BitmapFactory` does **just that**; it only decodes the size of the `Bitmap` and loads that data back into the options object's `outHeight` and `outWidth`.  It does not decode the actual `Bitmap` and return it to you.

If you want to actually get the `Bitmap` itself, remove that option and call `decodeFile()` again.